# NZEC error Spoj - Calculator

Tags: java

Hey i have problem NZEC on Spoj , I have to make calculator which have all operation ( +,-,/,*.%). In one line have to add operation for example : 
- 100 5 result 95
+ 100 100 result 200
* 1 1 result 1 etc.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    int wynik, liczba1, liczba2;
    Scanner odczyt = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {

        String zdanie = odczyt.nextLine();
        String[] ary = zdanie.split(" ");
        String x = ary[0];
        liczba1 = Integer.parseInt(ary[1]);
        liczba2 = Integer.parseInt(ary[2]);

        switch (x) {
        case "+":
            System.out.println(wynik = liczba1 + liczba2);
            break;
        case "-":
            System.out.println(liczba1 - liczba2);
            break;
        case "*":
            System.out.println(liczba1 * liczba2);
            break;
        case "/":
            System.out.println(liczba1 / liczba2);
            break;
        case "%":
            System.out.println(liczba1 % liczba2);
            break;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What's the problem? It seems fine

Comment: It's shown that i have to use try catch block :)